# Make html inputs flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to move button  [Like this demo](http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/game/twincol/) .Using css animation i can move in a straight forward animation. Is it possible to move off the screen and come in the screen and a particlular movement and direction to a box like the link.here is what i have done.

### HTML

```
<div id="box" style='width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;'/>

<button id="one" type="button" >Button1</button>
<button id="two" type="button" >Button2</button>
<button id="three" type="button">Button3</button>
```

### CSS

```
button{
-webkit-appearance:none;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 1px solid red;
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
}

#one, #two, #three
{
position:relative;

}

#one
{
  -webkit-animation:levelseven 16s  infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
}

#two
{

animation-direction:alternate;

/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation:levelseven_1 8s  infinite;
}

#three
{

animation-direction:alternate;

/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation:levelseven_2 10s  infinite;

}


@-webkit-keyframes levelseven /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  { left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  { left:100px; top:200px;}
75%  { left:150px; top:50px;}
100% {background:cyan; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes levelseven_1 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {background:darkgoldenrod; left:0px; top:200px;}
100% { left:0px; top:0px;}
  }


@-webkit-keyframes levelseven_2 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

[Here's demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wn9G/)

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: just a moment i got an idea let me try it out

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a logic very simple one](http://jsfiddle.net/8wn9G/7/)

What it basically does is it interchanges the classes periodically so that buttons navigation path changes so as to give view of dynamic path

```
function timer() {
   console.log("timer!");
   var className1 = $('#oneId').attr('class');
   var className2 = $('#twoId').attr('class');
   var className3 = $('#threeId').attr('class');

   $( "#oneId" ).removeClass(className1);
   $( "#twoId" ).removeClass(className2 );
   $( "#threeId" ).removeClass(className3);
   $( "#oneId" ).addClass(className2);
   $( "#twoId" ).addClass(className3);
   $( "#threeId" ).addClass( className1);



   // alert("class changed"+className1+":"+$('#oneId').attr('class')+","+className2+$('#twoId').attr('class')+","+className3+":"+$('#threeId').attr('class'));
}

window.setInterval(timer, 10000);
```

### Logic to make it more like the demo you have provided

- Create a number of paths that means you have to create more than 3 or 4  set of class one,two,three variants
- Periodically each path so that corresponding function for each path triggers and path changes accordingly period .The set period have to change when box exits square box's border so a 2000 or so milliseconds
- Give different starting and ending points for top and left of @-webkit-keyframes 
  so as each path looks unique
- Give values that are out of the range of box  so that it gives the effect of entering through one side and leaving through other